# How do I get a reference to canvas' container?

Tags: javascript, raphael

If I instantiate Raphael as below:-

```
var paper = Raphael(document.getElementById('id'), 200, 300);
```

then from `paper` how can I get a reference to the container DOM, i.e. one with the id 'id'?

My main aim is the get the width of the canvas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for `paper.canvas.parentElement`

Comment: Dunno if I am doing something wrong but I get `undefined` for this.

Comment: `paper.canvas` itself is just the DOM for the canvas (<svg> or <vml>, depending on browser). So pulling `parentElement` shouldn't be problematic unless your browser doesn't support it (I tried in Chrome). Another thing you can try is `parentNode`

Comment: Ohk. I tired in FF4. So, since `canvas` is the DOM of <svg>, so I tired `$(paper.canvas).parent()`. Thanks this works. :)

Answer (score 1):

Anyway answering my own question.

We can use `paper.width`, but I still don't know how to get a reference to its container.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `paper.el`? I think that MIGHT be how you access the base element.